# Allwinner V3s boot conditions

Tags: arm, bootloader, sbc, cortex, cortex-a

We've made our own SBC as part of a student project based on the Allwinner V3s, but it's not booting (no output on UART0, and it doesn't enter USB device mode (FEL) either).

What are all of the requirements for successfully booting?

- The MicroSD/eMMC (they use the same pins, but only 1 is connected at a time) is on SDC0.
- WiFi (RTL8723DS) is on SDC1.
- SPI0 is used for the screen
- UART0 test pinned out
- All the power domains are there (buck converters), but have max. 10 mV ripple
- X32 gets the correct 32.768 kHz
- The only suspect I have is that X24 gets a very fuzzy 400 kHz, but that might just be my bad oscilloscope.

[Schematic](https://pdfhost.io/v/NTOCM4Mgp_Schematic_Kavovar_20230226_1)

Answer (score 0):

Check

- Power sequencing (make sure reset is coming up later than 12ms after rails come up), make sure rails come up at the same time within 2ms make sure you have proper decoupling (follow eval board if there is one). Check bypass capacitors near processor, check all power domains. It's better if you can monitor all rails upon startup (need lots of probes)
- Clock, should be 24MHz, check it with a scope, make sure ground is good
- If you want USB boot, make sure BSP pin is low on start up

Try and get it into USB boot mode first. Also if you did the memory routing and haven't done it before it should match and eval board exactly, or you need to verify with signal integrity software or consultant.

Comment: Fortunatly memory is baked into the chip. Only problem I could image is wrong design with the 24MHz crystal, that makes it 400kHz. I've got 2 vias on both paths, but its still only 0.5cm from the chip.